# How to stop rspec from dropping the test database before tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have two Rails apps that use the same database. One app is managing the database through migrations but the other is just accessing it.

For some reason when I run tests with RSpec in the app that is not managing the database it drops the database before running the tests. But because this app does not know how to recreate the database all tests will fail.

How can I tell RSpec not to drop the database, just use it as it is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't need to migrate the database you can redefine rspecs-rails 
`spec:prepare` task like this:

`lib/tasks/patch_rspec_rails.rb`

```
Rake::Task["spec:prepare"].clear
namespace :spec do
  task :prepare do
    ENV['RACK_ENV'] = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'
  end 
end
```

The original `spec:prepare` task calls`test:prepare`, which setups the db.

The task `test:prepare` exists since [Rails 4.0](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/railties/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake#L66) (or maybe earlier). This task also exists within Rails 5.0. It is a hook for railsties to add test dependent setups. You can check its definition with `rake -W test:prepare`. That
the task is hit you can check with `rake --trace spec`.

[ActiveRecord uses this task](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L360) to check the migration state and setup the db.

When this task is not called, no db will be dropped or created.

But be aware, when some other gem uses `test:prepare` as a hook too plug into tests, it will not work.

*Edit:*

Since Rails 4.1 you can set `config.active_record.maintain_test_schema = false` within `config/environments/test.rb`. This way Rails should no longer try to migrate your test schema.

Comment: I am interested in trying to understand your solution better but I'm a little confused as to how this actually prevents the database from being dropped and failing on recreate because of the non-existence of schema.rb. From what i can gather it simply removes the invocation to `Rake::Task["test:prepare"].invoke`, which simply runs the migrations, and then only if that task is declared - meaning pre Rails 4.1.0. For Rails 4.1.0 and above that invocation doesn't even occur anyway.

Comment: Since Rails 4  or earlier the task `test:prepare` exists as a hook (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/railties/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake#L66). Within Rails 5 this task exists too (rake -W test:prep). ActiveRecord extends this task with a check for pending migrations (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L360). Within this task the drop occours also. When  `test:prepare` is not called, no database will be dropped or created. You have to ensure that the test dabase exists, but this was a given with the question.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent explanation :) There seems to be some misinformation floating around and I was even more confused because within the gem itself for me that task wasn't even being hit. It might be worth considering adding that explanation to the solution too - I think it does add value.

Comment: In JRuby there is something else happening. Even when I have this task in its place the database gets dropped. I checked with `rake -W spec` that my own spec:prepare task is called the same way it is called in MRI ruby.

Comment: commenting out the `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!` helped.

Comment: I don't know why jruby behaves different. But your hint with `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!`did reveal another option. Since Rails 4.1 you can set `config.active_record.maintain_test_schema = false` within `config/environments/test.rb`

Comment: Unfortunately neither the rake patch nor the `maintain_test_schema` config option worked for me; RSpec is still dropping the test DB. Rails 6.1.4.1, rspec-rails 5.0.2, rspec-core 3.10.1

Answer (score 3):

Ideally RSpec should be reinitialisation the database for testing to ensure your environment is in a reliably, predictable state.

What you could do is for the Rails app that isn't managing the database carry out a `rake db:schema:dump` to generate the schema.rb which will then be used by RSpec - of course make sure that your database.yml test configuration isn't pointing to your live database.

I know that this isn't technically a solution to your question but it should prevent the underlying issue which is causing your tests to fail.