# How to stop Rspec dropping the test database before tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I am updating an existing rails app to add tests. I notice that the database gets dropped prior to the test run.

I tried to follow the steps outlined in this question, [How to stop rspec from dropping the test database before tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238351/how-to-stop-rspec-from-dropping-the-test-database-before-tests), but had no luck.

Is there any RSpec documentation about this database drop functionality. And if not, how do I stop this from happening?

We are using these versions:
- rails: 5.1.2
- rspec-rails: 3.7.2

Comment: Are  yousing DatabaseCleaner ?

Comment: Why don't you want to drop the database? It's best practice to not depend on data existing in a local database for specs to run.